# ajax load should remain the status of my checkbox when checked

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem here using .load() ajax/jquery when I use it in pagination. the status of my checkbox will not remain when I go to another page. For example I checked 2 items in page 1 then when I go to page 2 to select another item then when I go back to page 1 to test if my checked item remain checked. unfortunately it became unchecked maybe because of the .load(). Please help me if there is alternative to use aside .load() to remain my checkbox checked.

here is my code for .load() ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});

    $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {


        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); 

        $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); 
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){

        });

        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load
    $('body').on('click', '.paginate_click', function(e){
    // Get all the checked boxes and store their ID in an array
    var ticked = [];
    $('.tick:checked').each(function(){
      ticked.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });


    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); 

    $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); 
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){
       // Content has loaded but is still raw
       // We loop through IDs and check'em
       ticked.forEach(function(val, i){
          $(val).prop('checked', true);
       });
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});     
});
</script>
```

hi @charleshaa it doesnt work this is what i did to my script

and here is my checkbox code

```
echo "<div id='a'><input type='checkbox' class='tick' name='items[$i]' id='$i' value='". $item['ItemID'] ."' >".$item['ItemName']."</div>";
```

What's wrong?? Im badly need help

Comment: You can store the checked boxes id inside a array in session and then while load check in the loop with the session and show it checked.

As the checked values are lost because on paginating the html changes on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep you checked boxes in a variable so you can recheck them after the load.

First add a class to your checkboxes `class="tick"`.

Then you would :

```
$(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {
    // Get all the checked boxes and store their ID in an array
    var ticked = [];
    $('.tick:checked').each(function(){
      ticked.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });


    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); 

    $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); 
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){
       // Content has loaded but is still raw
       // We loop through IDs and check'em
       ticked.forEach(function(val, i){
          $(val).prop('checked', true);
       });
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**

Also, it is preferable not to use the `.click()` notation, instead, you should always use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

In this example, you would write it like this :

```
$('body').on('click', '.paginate_click', function(e){
  //code
});
```

It is much better for performance as it only attaches one event listener to body, instead of attaching one to every `.paginate_click`.

Check my comment about the unique IDs and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi @charleshaa it doesnt work :(

Comment: ticked.push($(this).attr("id")); is this attr("id") or it should be a class because I used class="tick"

Comment: Now you need to assign a unique ID attribute to your checkboxes. for example `<input class="tick" id="checkbox-1" ... />`.